Добавление поля для ввода в active bar в vscode
В данный момент я пишу расширение для Visual Studio Code и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно чтобы в окне расширения, которое открывается с active bar было поле для ввода. При этом значение должно сохранится в долгую память. chatGPT выдает нерабочий код, а в официальных доках ничего об это не сказано(Там просто инструкция по выводу расширения в active bar)
Вот что я имею ввиду:
